# How to Post List of Objects through AJAX to Spring Controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am trying to POST a list of forms through AJAX.

```js
$('html').on('click', '#update-cartentries', function() {
  var forms = $('html').find("form.updateCartForm");
  alert('there are : ' + forms.length + ' forms');
  var entryData = new Array();

  $("form.updateCartForm").each(function(index, element) {
    var updatedQty = $(element).find('input[name=quantity]').val();
    var initialQuantity = $(element).find('input[name=initialQuantity]').val();
    var entryNumber = $(element).find('input[name=entryNumber]').val();

    if (initialQuantity != updatedQty) {
      var entry = {};
      entry.entryNumber = entryNumber;
      entry.quantity = updatedQty;
      entryData.push(entry);
    }
  });

  alert('Entry Data: ' + entryData);

  if (entryData.length > 0) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/update-entries',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        "entries": entryData
      },
      success: function(response) {
        // alert("Success" + response);
        window.location.reload();
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // log the error to the console
        // alert("Something Went wrong" + errorThrown);
        console.log("The following error occurred: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update-entries", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String updateCartEntries(final Model model, @RequestBody final UpdateCartEntryList entries, final BindingResult bindingResult,
                                final HttpServletRequest request, final RedirectAttributes redirectModel) throws CMSItemNotFoundException
{
  // ...
}
```

It is not hitting the controller method and generates a 405 error code in the browser.

The `UpdateCartEntryList` class has a List of another object which has 2 properties, `entryNumber` and `quantity`.

Can anyone tell me the correct process or code to resolve the issue? Is anything wrong in the code? Please identify and let me know.

Comment: A 405 error means Method Unsupported, ie. you're sending a GET to a POST endpoint or vice versa. I can see the logic has both set to POST, but check the configuration just in case

Comment: What are the contents of `entryData` after the for each loop?

Comment: @PrerakSola It prints [Object ]

Comment: Print it on console and see what it contains.

Comment: @PrerakSola It prints as "Entry Data: [object Object]"

Comment: I want to know the content of the object. Either remove string concatenation while printing on the console or stringify the object.

Comment: Don't coerce the value. Just do `console.log(entryData)` after the `each()` has finished

Comment: [{"entryNumber":"0","quantity":"2"}] -  this is what it prints.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Config is ok.

Comment: Hey guys I am getting 415 error - media type not supported. @PrerakSola

Comment: Your data being sent is not being accepted by the server.

Comment: Add `dataType: 'json',` to your ajax method and try `"entries": JSON.stringify(entryData)`

Comment: The probleme is in your entryData structure.

you mentioned that The UpdateCartEntryList class has a List of another object, so your data must be like "entries" : {xxxx:entryData } when xxxx is the attribute name of the list inside UpdateCartEntryList